# Mean of values in time series with different range

Tags: r, time, merge, mean

I need to average values over different time steps. Here is the thing:
I have a table 1 with my time values at the beginning and end of my pumping.

Table 1

| Timestamp_Start | Timestamp_End |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-02 17:57:25 | 2021-06-02 18:06:37 |
| 2021-06-02 18:33:19 | 2021-06-02 18:42:31 |
| 2021-06-02 19:09:13 | 2021-06-02 19:18:25 |
| 2021-06-02 19:44:42 | 2021-06-02 19:53:53 |
| 2021-06-02 20:20:36 | 2021-06-02 20:29:48 |
| ... | ... |

and this table with my X concentrations :

Table 2

| Start | End | Concentration X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/06/2021 17:57 | 02/06/2021 17:58 | 25.5 |
| 02/06/2021 17:58 | 02/06/2021 17:59 | 25.1 |
| 02/06/2021 17:59 | 02/06/2021 18:00 | 24.7 |
| 02/06/2021 18:00 | 02/06/2021 18:01 | 23.9 |
| 02/06/2021 18:01 | 02/06/2021 18:02 | 27.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:02 | 02/06/2021 18:03 | 24.3 |
| 02/06/2021 18:03 | 02/06/2021 18:04 | 24.1 |
| 02/06/2021 18:04 | 02/06/2021 18:05 | 26.7 |
| 02/06/2021 18:05 | 02/06/2021 18:06 | 27.3 |
| 02/06/2021 18:06 | 02/06/2021 18:07 | 25.8 |
| 02/06/2021 18:07 | 02/06/2021 18:08 | 29.9 |
| 02/06/2021 18:08 | 02/06/2021 18:09 | 30.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:09 | 02/06/2021 18:10 | 31.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:10 | 02/06/2021 18:11 | 28.9 |
| 02/06/2021 18:11 | 02/06/2021 18:12 | 25.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:12 | 02/06/2021 18:13 | 56.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:13 | 02/06/2021 18:14 | 51.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:14 | 02/06/2021 18:15 | 35.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:15 | 02/06/2021 18:16 | 34.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:16 | 02/06/2021 18:17 | 26.9 |
| 02/06/2021 18:17 | 02/06/2021 18:18 | 15.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:18 | 02/06/2021 18:19 | 11.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:19 | 02/06/2021 18:20 | 17.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:20 | 02/06/2021 18:21 | 25.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:21 | 02/06/2021 18:22 | 24.1 |
| 02/06/2021 18:22 | 02/06/2021 18:23 | 21.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:23 | 02/06/2021 18:24 | 26.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:24 | 02/06/2021 18:25 | 32.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:25 | 02/06/2021 18:26 | 24.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:26 | 02/06/2021 18:27 | 26.8 |
| 02/06/2021 18:27 | 02/06/2021 18:28 | 29.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:28 | 02/06/2021 18:29 | 26.7 |
| 02/06/2021 18:29 | 02/06/2021 18:30 | 26.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:30 | 02/06/2021 18:31 | 26.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:31 | 02/06/2021 18:32 | 26.7 |
| 02/06/2021 18:32 | 02/06/2021 18:33 | 28.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:33 | 02/06/2021 18:34 | 24.1 |
| 02/06/2021 18:34 | 02/06/2021 18:35 | 26.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:35 | 02/06/2021 18:36 | 34.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:36 | 02/06/2021 18:37 | 33.2 |
| 02/06/2021 18:37 | 02/06/2021 18:38 | 35.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:38 | 02/06/2021 18:39 | 30.1 |
| 02/06/2021 18:39 | 02/06/2021 18:40 | 35.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:40 | 02/06/2021 18:41 | 39.8 |
| 02/06/2021 18:41 | 02/06/2021 18:42 | 22.1 |
| 02/06/2021 18:42 | 02/06/2021 18:43 | 22.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:43 | 02/06/2021 18:44 | 22.4 |
| 02/06/2021 18:44 | 02/06/2021 18:45 | 11.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:45 | 02/06/2021 18:46 | 17.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:46 | 02/06/2021 18:47 | 20.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:47 | 02/06/2021 18:48 | 22.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:48 | 02/06/2021 18:49 | 24.8 |
| 02/06/2021 18:49 | 02/06/2021 18:50 | 29.6 |
| 02/06/2021 18:50 | 02/06/2021 18:51 | 30.5 |
| 02/06/2021 18:51 | 02/06/2021 18:52 | 36.5 |

I would like in output a table like this : 
Table 1

| Timestamp_Start | Timestamp_End | Mean X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-02 17:57:25 | 2021-06-02 18:06:37 | value = mean of values in Table 2 between this time range |
| 2021-06-02 18:33:19 | 2021-06-02 18:42:31 | value = mean of values in Table 2 between this time range |
| 2021-06-02 19:09:13 | 2021-06-02 19:18:25 | value = mean of values in Table 2 between this time range |
| 2021-06-02 19:44:42 | 2021-06-02 19:53:53 | value = mean of values in Table 2 between this time range |
| 2021-06-02 20:20:36 | 2021-06-02 20:29:48 | value = mean of values in Table 2 between this time range |

I need to delete the seconds in Table 1 to be able to merge them with Table2. I am already stuck on this point.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What language? What have you tried already? Also please provide reproducible data

Comment: R langage sorry. </b>
I found how to round values so I have all my time series in the same and the right format.</b>
I tried this sentence : 'A=merge(Table1, Table2, by="Timestamp_Start")', but it doesn't work, I can't make the mean of values in this way.</b>
What do you mean when you talk about "reproducible data"?</b>
Thanks

Comment: By "reproducible data", Robin means a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please consider making one as it allows us to help you in the best way.